# Get data remotely from another device with get

Tags: postman

currently I am getting data through postman via GET REQUEST- http://localhost:5000/categories. I want to be able to access this data from another device, through the same request in a different device(not collection). Would this be possible, if so what must I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do that with "syncing" your work. Syncing makes all your postman data available when you're signed in to your postman account.

to do that, install postman and sign in with your Login data or alternatively access postman on the web.

When you're logged in, your data is synced across devices.

Comment: I'm suppose to be able to share a link to another person and they use this link to get data through a get request on postman.

Comment: For example I provide you with "http://localhost:5000/categories" and you add this to a get  request on postman. Then you'll see my data. I'm not sure how this is done. Still noob at this :(

Comment: I'm afraid that this won't work like that. You can only share postman entities with using Collections.

Comment: When I use collections, it seems like user must be connected to a server to view the collection. With the sample above, user must be connected to port 5000 to view it. Is there a way I can get around this?